# Debugging Quicklisp when the backtrace lacks information

Tags: common-lisp, slime, quicklisp, ecl

What's your general approach when quickload fails? I guess I'd like to know the line that provoked the problem, but all I'm given is a backtrace with a reference to a bytecompiled-function. How should I proceed to determine which package, file and form causes the problem?

### Update

My environment is ECL in Emacs. The backtrace is provided by the SLIME debugger.

Comment: This depends on the IDE and or Lisp you are using. You might want to provide more details to your question.

Comment: So, where is the backtrace?

Comment: @RainerJoswig Done. The IDE is SLIME and Lisp is ECL but I'd be interested in knowing if there's a portable approach.

Comment: @sds The backtrace is provided by SLIME.

Comment: @MichaelFox: please copy and paste the backtrace into your question.

Comment: If you have your cursor on the frame in the SLIME debugger, then press V  . This stands for 'view source for the frame'. Alternatively move over the symbol and press M-.   .  If you want to look at all possible keybindings, the press c-h m   . In Slime m-. on a symbol will try to find its source.

Comment: @RainerJoswig V doesn't work in the scenario described by the user. It takes you to the source of code that asked for the the file that filed to be compiled. although unsophisticated I just start compiling all the files in the system until I find the error and get a backtrace I can debug (with V)

Answer (score 0):

Quicklisp uses ASDF (which usually comes preinstalled), you can try to use it directly to get more detailed error. See [manual](https://common-lisp.net/project/asdf/asdf.html#Loading-a-system).

1. Put (or symlink) your system in one of the standard locations, as subdirectory for example "foo" under

   - ~/common-lisp/ or
   - ~/.local/share/common-lisp/source/.
2. Try to load it

(asdf:load-system :foo)